# how do I retain my imap emails when changing email host providers? export/import?

Tags: email, imap

Running Linux Debian Jessie with claws email client...

I am changing my email hosting service provider (I have no control over the server--so I can't back up the emails on the server itself.). I use imap. The problem is I don't want to lose my current emails.  The email client will sync with the new server and delete all my current email.

What is the best way to stop the deletion of the current emails?

I was thinking export them before switching servers, then import them back after the first sync on the new server. But, I keep seeing import options, but no export options.  I am using claws email client.

So I need to know how to export my emails or come up with some other solution.  Any ideas helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no "export/import" options because you usually don't need any – IMAP allows doing the same directly:

1. Add the new IMAP account to Claws. (If you don't have an account on the new server yet, use *File → Add Mailbox → MH* to create a local folder tree, typically at `~/Mail/`.)
2. Drag and drop all your IMAP folders to the new account. This will move the actual messages, so it will take a while.
3. Remove the old account from Claws.

If you moved the folders to a local directory, simply repeat this later to upload them back to the new server.

You can also use tools like OfflineIMAP to download an entire account to your computer, or isync / imapsync / the same OfflineIMAP to copy everything to the new IMAP server.

Comment: I will try that... Will that save all the emails locally, if I am Also, I just found OfflineIMAP and was wondering if that would work.

Comment: My comment got saved wrong.... 'Will that save all the emails locally, if I am ' should not be there.

Comment: Yes, if you drag the messages to a local folder, they will be stored fully in that local folder. (Claws uses the MH format; Thunderbird supports Maildir and mbox; OfflineIMAP also uses Maildir; all of them can be inspected with a text editor.)

Comment: Your suggestion worked real well using the **MH** local folder.  I have yet to explore OfflineIMAP, but intend to, as it looks useful. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

IMAP syncs email instead of downloading. If you want to secure the email backup before moving to the new provider, configure your email client with POP and download all emails then move to new hosting provider.

Comment: While that solution is not bad, another better solution was already offered and accepted.